# using belongsTo() function gives me error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, belongs-to

So I have this relationship defined in the `holiday` model to access the `holiday_type` model.

MHoliday model:

```
use Arkitecht\Attributions\Traits\Attributions;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class MHoliday extends Model
{
    use Attributions;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $table = 'm_holiday';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'holiday_name',
        'holiday_date',
        'holiday_type_id',
        'office_id',
        'public_holiday_flag'
    ];

    public function holidayType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\MHolidayType', 'holiday_type_id');
    }

    public function officeName()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\MOffice', 'office_id');
    }
}
```

MHolidayType model:

```
namespace App;

use Arkitecht\Attributions\Traits\Attributions;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class MHolidayType extends Model
{
    use Attributions;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $table = 'm_holiday_type';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'holiday_type_name'
    ];
}
```

MOffice model:

```
namespace App;

use Arkitecht\Attributions\Traits\Attributions;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class MOffice extends Model
{
    use Attributions;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $table = 'm_office';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'office_name',
        'office_authority_id',
        'note',
        'first_name',
        'employee_authority_id',
        'note',
    ];
}
```

Then, I try show the result like:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ $item->officeName->office_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->holidayType->holiday_type_name}}</td>
</tr>
```

The Office name gives me result, but the holiday type throws me error "Trying to get property of non-object". What could be lacking?

**Update**

In my view, it is partly like this:

```
@foreach($holiday as $item)
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="items-selected" value="{{ $item->id }}"></td>
        <td>{{ $item->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->holiday_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->holidayType->holiday_type_name }}</td>

        <td>{{ $item->officeName->office_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->public_holiday_flag }}</td>
@endforeach
```

In the Holiday controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\MHoliday;
use App\MOffice;
use App\MHolidayType;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class HolidayController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $keyword = $request->get('holiday');
        $getSearchby = $request->searchby;
        $perPage = 25;

        if ($keyword) {
            $holiday = MHoliday::join('m_office', 'm_office.id', '=', 'm_holiday.office_id')
                    ->where('m_office.office_name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                    ->paginate($perPage);
        } else {
            $holiday = MHoliday::paginate($perPage);
        }

        return view('holiday.index', compact('holiday','searchby','getSearchby'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your controller file with function that returns $item

Comment: @AmitGupta I added it now.

Comment: Are you sure all of your `m_holiday`'s `holiday_type_id` exists in your `m_holiday_type` table?

Comment: before return view add echo "<pre>"; print_r($holiday); die;

Comment: Check if all the data is coming because Trying to get property of non-object issue is related with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to debug the result for your collection first because this exception mines that your table

> `m_holiday_type`

have no records who match the relation.

do this in your controller before the `return view` :

```
dd($holidays);
```

and tell display me the result please.